# PHP Check how old a symlink file is

Tags: php, symlink

I have a download script which is creating a link to a file using `symlink()`. I'm trying to create a script to delete the links after they are 1 hour old. However, when I try and check how old the file is with `filemtime()`, I just get the modification time of the actual original (target) file and not the symlink.

Here's my current code:

```
$filename = '/var/www/html/files/myfile.rar';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
```

What should i do to check the last modified time of the actual symlink instead of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, [`filemtime()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) and [`stat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) will follow symlinks, but [`lstat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.lstat.php) will not.

> This function is identical to the `stat()` function except that if the filename parameter is a symbolic link, the status of the symbolic link is returned, not the status of the file pointed to by the symbolic link.

For example:

```
<?php

function getSymlinkMtime($symlinkPath)
{
    $stat = lstat($symlinkPath);

    return isset($stat['mtime']) ? $stat['mtime'] : null;
}
```

could be used in place of `filemtime()`.

Your full example, in that approach, would be:

```
<?php

$filename = '/var/www/html/files/myfile.rar';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", getSymlinkMtime($filename));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, although your missing a closing bracket in the return function.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP function [`lstat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lstat.php):

```
$stat = lstat('/var/www/html/files/myfile.rar');
print_r($stat);
```

Gives you loads of information like atime (last access), ctime (time created) and mtime (last modify).

Answer (score -3):

Probably, you can't get attributes of symlink. You can create file where you can store the information about link.